# Download failed, retrying... Downloading https://repo.magento.com/archives/magento/magento2-base/magento-magento2-base-2.3.0.0.zip

Tags: magento2, composer, repository, download

I need to say, its really hard and sadly magento typically that nothing works out of the box as it should if you follow offical step-by-step tutorials.

Since a few hours or better days I try to install Magento2 over composer.
Actually, it hangs up while downloading all the packages.

The biggest one, I guess is the magento2-base...

If the download is nearly by 100% I get some "code" like this:
"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)"

```
Download failed, retrying...
```

Downloading https://repo.magento.com/archives/magento/magento2-base/magento-magento2-base-2.3.0.0.zip
Downloading (xx%)

Than the download restarts... several times but not possibility to get the package.

After a few problems I faced, which looks like that the magento repo server has some connection problems, this seems to be the hardest nut.
Has anyone ever faced such problems? In the best case excactly this error?

Thanks for your help.

Bye

Timm

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command:

> php composer.phar create-project
>   --repository=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition=2.3.* --stability=stable
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/development/magento23

Go to your directory. Download composer. Change **/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/development/magento23** to your project directory.